# How to use only Times font in main text with KOMA and how to remove dots in the page heading?

Tags: koma-script

I just want to use Times New Roman for my main text with KOMA. All other fonts should be changed to Arial. Could you help me out with this issue?

[image: Pls. check: How to get rid of Times here?] 
Furthermore, how to delete those dots after this numbering?
Please see my fancyhdr code part attached.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Cheers,

mldmnn

```
    %Generelles Seitenlayout
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}
    \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\let\uppercase\relax\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark}}
    \chead[]{}
    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\let\uppercase\relax\normalfont\sffamily\bfserie        \leftmark}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}
    \lfoot[]{}
    \cfoot[]{}
    \rfoot[]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \setlength\headwidth{15cm}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%Kapitelanfänge
    \lhead[]{}
    \chead[]{} 
    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\let\uppercase\relax\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries        \leftmark}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}
    \lfoot[]{}
    \cfoot[]{}
    \rfoot[]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \setlength\headwidth{15cm}
    }
    %\voffset = 1.3cm
    %\hoffset = 0.8cm
    \textwidth = 15cm
    \textheight = 24cm
    \fancypagestyle{appendixchap}{%Kapitelanfänge
    \lhead[]{}
    \chead[]{} 
    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\let\uppercase\relax\bfseries\leftmark}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
    \lfoot[]{}
    \cfoot[]{}
    \rfoot[]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \setlength\headwidth{15cm}
    \setlength\headsep{-.5cm}
    }
```

Comment: Works just with a standard class, nothing special.

Comment: Pls. see my picture ... TOC is still mixed, too ... Do you know how to delete those dots after this numbering?

Comment: Moreover, how to force KOMA to use sans-serif fonts only for one page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do. Unfortunaly there is no MWE in your question. Maybe you are looking for something like

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=noenddot% <- no dot at the end of numbers
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\textsf,
  tocpagenumberformat=\textsf
]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\textsf,
  pagenumberformat=\textsf
]{default}{figure}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\textsf,
  pagenumberformat=\textsf
]{default}{table}

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\appendix
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=noenddot% <- no dot at the end of numbers
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries,
  tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries
]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries,
  pagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries
]{default}{figure}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries,
  pagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries
]{default}{table}

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\usekomafont{disposition}}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\appendix
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: `txfonts` has a number of problems in spacing. Better use the combination `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` (that are also actively developed).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the hint. Normally I do not use Times at all.

Comment: In addition to what egreg pointed out, `newtxtext` uses `tgheros` (an Helvetica clone) as sans-derif default; it also already correctly scaled. Loading `helvet` is thus not necessary.

Comment: Thx so much! I've already used numbers=noenddot%, but the dots still apear. I use the fancyhdr btw

Comment: I've just added my fancyhdr code part to my question

Comment: Please ask a new question and add there a real MWE showing the issue. By default `fancyhdr` does not take option `numbers=noenddot` into account: `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` must be redefined to replace the hard coded dot by `\autodot` (or to remove the dot).